# JQGrid rows disappears after initial loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

JQGrid rows disappears after initial loading...

Comment: It seems to be the exact duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: I mean that the rules of stackoverflow don't allows to post the same question multiple times. Your question can be deleted and your account can be blocked. I recommend you to delete the duplicate question. You can edit the previous question by clicking on "edit" link which you find under the text of your question.

Comment: I posted you already the link to [my old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9047197/315935) in comment to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34350178/315935). I think it's close to what you want to implement.

Comment: Can somebody provide me a solution, why the rows disappears in initally..I have nothing done related with sorting..

Comment: One can help you only if one knows what you do. You didn't posted and code or the demo. How you imagine somebody can help you?

Comment: As I am working for high secure major client, data and code logic / pattern security must be kept secured. I need the cause for this problem (_JQGrid rows disappears after initial loading_) and I will check on my code.

Comment: Is your code secure? Is your code logic so genial that nobody else should see it? I think that you are able to solve all problems yourself in the case and you don't need to ask other why you code works incorrectly. I suppose that the rows disappears because you use jqGrid in the wrong way.

Comment: CLIENT does not want their asset(`code`) in PUBLIC..If I posted here, it will be in public. Its OK. I am using the jqgrid as I worked in my previous applications which are working well. I need in which area of jqgrid(that is `onloadcomplete` or `gridcomplete` or `somewhere`)  where and what to check for this records disappearing problem that too only initially..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to stop a JqGrid from flickering on reload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106552/is-it-possible-to-stop-a-jqgrid-from-flickering-on-reload)